# How can I get the data values from a function?

Tags: function, get, gnuplot

I have a question, how can I get the data values from a function in gnuplot? For example I do

```
plot [0:pi] sin(x)
```

but I want to get the data values from this plot, how can I do that?.

Comment: you can save the data in a file then open the file and read its values

Comment: This is a good question.  Clear and simple. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [table mode](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-27000043.61).

```
set samples 100
set table "sin.dat"
plot [0:pi] sin(x)
```